# using reducer namespace in redux to practice DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to add a loader for each action, like the buttons will display `loading` when dispatch ([see demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/y7vj468qyj))

```
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.resetItem()}>
          {this.props.loading ? "loading..." : "Reset"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>
          {this.props.loading ? "loading..." : "Approve"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is all button will show `loading` because my reducer has a global loading state only

```
export function items(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "APPROVE":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case "APPROVED":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        item: {
          status: "approved"
        }
      };
    case "RESET":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case "DONE_RESET":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        item: {
          status: "pending"
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I can hardcode approve_loading, reset_loading and so on but that's redundancy, any technique to do namespacing in reducer?

Comment: Check this article on medium, which is extremely detailed and addresses the same issue as you mention https://kickstarter.engineering/namespacing-actions-for-redux-d9b55a88b1b1

Answer (score 0):

Neat question - have never run into this myself but I'm wondering if something like this could work. You can use `combineReducers()` to namespace, so a perhaps not entirely elegant approach could be:

```
export function itemsReducer(index) {
  return function items(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case `APPROVE_${index}`:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
        };
      case `APPROVED_${index}`:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          item: {
            status: 'approved',
          },
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
}

const reducers = {};
//could add more indexes here for more items;
[0, 1].forEach(i => {
  reducers[`item${i}`] = itemsReducer(i);
});

export default combineReducers(reducers);

//state = {
//  item0: {...},
//  item1: {...}
//}
```

Your actions would then need to include the appropriate index (0 or 1) when dispatching (e.g. `APPROVED_1`) so the correct `item` state will get set.

Equivalent syntax:

```
export default combineReducers({
    item0: itemsReducer(0),
    item1: itemsReducer(1)
});
```